# Python Delete Text under Certain Tag

Tags: python, html

I would like to delete certain text under the specific tag in HTML.
I want to delete the last one under `<TEXT>`.

I think when there is `<TYPE>GRAPHIC`, `<TEXT>` has some wired contents.
I just would like to delete contents of `<TEXT>`

Please help me. thank you

````````
</DIV>

<DIV align="left" style="font-size: 10pt; margin-top: 6pt">In connection with the Annual Report on Form 20-F of SearchMedia Holdings Limited (the &#147;Company&#148;)for the fiscal year ended December&nbsp;31, 2010, as filed with the Securities and Exchange Commissionon the date hereof (the &#147;Report&#148;), I, Wilfred Chow, Chief Financial Officer of the Company, hereby certify, pursuant to 18 U.S.C. &#167;1350, as adopted pursuant to Section&nbsp;906 of the Sarbanes-Oxley Actof 2002, that, to my knowledge:
</DIV>

</BODY>
</HTML>
</TEXT>
</DOCUMENT>
<DOCUMENT>
<TYPE>GRAPHIC
<SEQUENCE>7
<FILENAME>g27632g2763201.gif
<DESCRIPTION>GRAPHIC
<TEXT>
begin 644 g27632g2763201.gif
M1TE&.#EA50)Q`^8``'EV=1D6%M73T8J(B)"-BD5#1*FFI=W;VOO[^H."@CDW
M-I>4D\'`P,C&Q\_+R$Q*2@@&!RTI*+6SLKV[NO;V]:6CH:VKJ>7DXVMH9X&4
MC?+R\9V;F5514>[M["0E)%E6565B8>KIZ%%-3%U:66UJ:N+AX.?EXZ_,PM#.
MS;"MK+BVM7!M;,;$Q)B6E:"=G(>%A;^]O,3"P=?6U<K)R&AE9)&JHV!=7-_>
MW>3BXF]_>G]\?.SKZDA%1>CFY<_-S+*PK\*_OC`M+.'@W^WLZS\\/"@E)9>P
MJ;JXM^CGYJ*@G]K8UX.`?\W+RLO(Q9J8EW.$?JNGI1\<').0C_7T\]+0SW-Q
M<+75RXR(AV-@7^_O[O/S\EM85Z&[LV-S;\;#P@X+#*;#NDQ(1T-`/U-04#0Q
M,+K;T2LH)R0@($E'1XRBFHF'A[#.Q!01Q54BHG)R(?'SM"0%)=6?W]_45-
M2OCX]_'P[T%'0VEG9U)/3Y&.CS(O+[[@UHJ@F%AC7\#BV/___R'Y!```````
M+`````!5`G$#``?_@'^"@X2%AH>(B8J+C(V.CY"1DI.4E9:7F)F:FYR=GI^@
MH:*CI*6FE7@/JJNLK:ZOL+&RL[2UMK>XN;J[O+V^O[``I\/$Q<;'R)%?57G-
MSL_0T=+3U-76U]C9VMO<W=[?X.'BT1\%R>?HZ>KKE%\-[/#Q\O.,"^;T^/GZ
M^X_N_/\``W*R)["@P8/$_"%<R-`@P880(TIDI'"BQ8O)'F+<R%%@Q8X@0V[2
M*+*DR7,?3ZI<B8@DRY<P.:4T5&()A@4A-G5PLJ.0A#Q*",W(<X`1$PM_8$A@
````````

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

you may try `lxml`,  or `pyquery`. with which it can be very easy to manipulate HTML / XML documents